# A way to access class/method from parent form using usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls

I would like to have some advice or possible solution to access a class or method from the `parentForm` to `userControl`.

I wanted to reuse the `loadquizes()` which was just to reload the `dataGrid` from `gradingSheet` form using the `userControl` on the same form.

my structure of my project was:

```
Mainform(Form) 
|_Gradingsheet(MDIchild/Also a Form)
        |_mypanel(inside the Gradingsheet)
              |_updatequizes(usercontrol)
```

`GradingSheet` code to call the `userControl`

```
private void updateQuizToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        quiz = new UpdateQuizes();
        quiz.lrnLbl.Text = MelrnLbl.Text;
        quiz.nameLbl.Text = MEnameLbl.Text;
        quiz.quartervar.Text = quartervar.Text;
        quiz.GradeLbl.Text = GradeLbl.Text;
        quiz.subjLbl.Text = subjLbl.Text;
        quiz.yearLbl.Text = yearLbl.Text;
        UserControlPanel.Controls.Clear();
        UserControlPanel.Controls.Add(quiz);
    }
```

Inside the `UserControl`:

```
void insertQuiz()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
        {
            string query = "UPDATE GimenezSystem.quizes SET Q"+(quizcombo.SelectedIndex + 1) + " =?newval WHERE Year=?year and GradeLevel=?glevel and Subject=?subj and Quarter =?qtr and LRN =?LRN";
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?LRN", lrnLbl.Text);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?quiz", quiz);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?newval", NewVal.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?year", yearLbl.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?glevel", GradeLbl.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?subj", subjLbl.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?qtr", quartervar.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    GradingSheet gr = GradingSheet.ActiveForm as GradingSheet;
                    gr.loadquizes();//here it gives me an error of object is not set for reference of instance or something like that T.T
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
                }

            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to re-use the method multiple places then consider implementing the method in a separate class and use that in whichever from or user control you want instead of having the method in a `Form` or `UserControl`. below code lines is the issue.

```
          GradingSheet gr = GradingSheet.ActiveForm as GradingSheet;
                gr.loadquizes();//he
```

Instread have it in a separate class like

```
public class Helper
{
  public void LoadQuizes()
  {
     //code here
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, how would i do that approach? I've already make that method as public i thought that would set ok to access from other places